# How to handle Nan values when computing weighted mean

Tags: python, pandas

I have a weights series like below:

```
a  0.2
b  0.3
c  0.5
```

and a dataframe:

```
   a    b   c
1  1    2   2
2  Nan  2   2
3  Nan  1   Nan
...
```

I want to compute the weighted mean of the dataframe like this:

```
(dataframe * weights).sum(axis=1)
```

The problem is that when the value of the dataframe is Nan i want the corresponding weight to be added equally to the other weights. For example for the second row weights should be 0.4 for b and 0.6 for c. And for the third row weight matrix should be 1 for b.

Comment: On the second row, as `a=Nan` you did `weight(a)/2 = 0.1` and added that to the weight of `b` and `c`?

Comment: @ChuckM yeah exactly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you can make an adjusted weights matrix

```
df2 = dataframe.copy()
df2[pd.notnull(df2)] = 1
df2 = df2 * weight
df2 = df2.multiply(1/df2.sum(axis=1), axis=0)
df2
```

results in this weigths matrix

```
    a   b   c
row             
1   0.2     0.300   0.500
2   NaN     0.375   0.625
3   NaN     1.000   NaN
```

then `(df2 * dataframe).sum(axis=1)` results in

```
row
1    1.8
2    2.0
3    1.0
dtype: float64
```

This can be done slightly quicker by using [DafaFrame.where()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.where.html)

```
df2 = dataframe.where(pd.isnull,1) * weight
result = (df2.multiply(1 / df2.sum(axis=1), axis=0) * dataframe).sum(axis=1)
```

Comment: I added a shorter method using `DataFrame.where`

Comment: Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 5):

You can use numpy's [average for masked arrays](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ma.average.html), designed exactly for that use case. Let `s` be the weight series, and `df` the dataframe:

```
np.ma.average(np.ma.array(df.values, mask=df.isnull().values), 
              weights=s.values, axis=1)
```

The `.data` property contains the result:

```
array([ 1.8,  2. ,  1. ])
```

---

**Edit**: as suggested in the comments you can convert the result to a series:

```
pd.Series(np.ma.average(np.ma.array(df.values, mask=df.isnull().values), 
                        weights=s.values, axis=1).data, index=df.index)
```

Comment: Nice shot +1 ;)

Comment: Thanks @jezrael :)

Comment: Thanks for your effort. I accepted the other answer only because it was first. +1

Comment: Nice answer. Perhaps clarify that `df` is `dataframe` and `s` is `weight` in the original post

Comment: What if there are missing value in the weighted series

Comment: Just drop the corresponding rows in the dataframe?